# How can the following integral be solved with substitution techniques or integration by parts?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$ \int \ln(2+3\cos^2x)dx $$ This is considered to be a difficult integral.Unfortunately, i haven't managed to solve it by any means.

Comment: [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+ln%282+%2B+3cos%5E2x%29) gives no clear answer

Answer (score 5):

If you use the substitution $x=\arctan t$ you may see that the integral is equivalent to:
$$ \int \frac{\log\left(2+\frac{3}{1+t^2}\right)}{1+t^2}\,dt = \log\left(2+\frac{3}{1+t^2}\right)\arctan(t)+\int \frac{6 t\arctan(t)}{5+7 t^2+2 t^4}\,dt$$
that depends on the [inverse tangent integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangentIntegral.html) / dilogarithm. So our function may have a nice Fourier expansion (or an expansion in terms of Legendre polynomials) but it is not an elementary function at all. Things may change dramatically if some particular integration endpoints are given - for instance:
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log(2+3\cos^2 x)\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\log\left(\frac{4+\sqrt{15}}{2}\right).$$